# A creep mathematical model of alloy steel for making springs

Tags: springs, creep

I'm searching for a mathematical approach to well describe the creep （or stress relaxation）of helical-coil compression spring.I've got the spring parts and can Experiment with these parts .I need extra theoretical analysis which my experiment is trying to support.

Comment: Related: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/2242/33

Comment: You need to understand Young's Modulus for the metal and determine the minimum load before creep occurs and the relation between it and fourth dimension leading (time)